# Получение статуса шаринга в Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

Появилась необходимость в приложении сделать функцию "Сделай пост, получи бонус". С ВК ни каких проблем нет, все просто и понятно, но вот с Facebook появились проблемы.

Использую самую последнюю версию `Facebook SDK`, шаринг делаю следующим кодом:

```
   FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
   content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"link"];
   [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:viewController
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
```

Окно шаринга открывается в Safari или в приложении Facebook если оно установлено. Все работает, все норм.. но загвоздка в том, как получить статус "пост успешно отправлен"?

Пробовал использовать `FBSDKSharingDelegate`, но метод:

```
-(void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{
```

возвращает в `results` пустоту, т.е. не важно, закроешь ты окошко сафари или сделаешь пост и потом закроешь, все равно `results` будет пустой.

Может кто подсказать как правильно настроить `Facebook SDK` для данной задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наткнулся на этот вопрос здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314262/facebook-share-dialog-callback-not-working-in-ios

Это старая проблема. Или же FB (согласно своим [Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5)) нарочно не возвращает ничего в results

Comment: Спасибо! Очень печально что такая популярная сеть как FB делает такие странные ограничения, хотя казалось бы, очевидная функция.